# Finding a quadrature rule for symmetric integral

Tags: numerical-methods, quadrature

I have to find a quadrature rule that approximates the integral of $f(x)$ such that
$$\int_{-h}^{h} f(x) = w_1f(x_1) + w_2f(x_2) + w_3f(x_3) + E$$ where the weights $w_i$ and points $x_i$ are to be found. I also have the extra condition:
$$\int_{-h}^{h} f(x) = \int_{-h}^{h} f(-x)$$
I'm not sure how this extra condition factors into finding the required constants; usually I would set $f(x)$ to be a linear function, then quadratic, then cubic etc. up until the last order of polynomial that we know it will be exact to. I don't know how accurate it has to be, but I'm assuming this particular rule will be exact up to cubics as it resembles Simpson's rule, so since I have six constants to find, the symmetric condition will need to provide 2 more (I estimate).

However, running through my usual method of setting $f(x) = 1$, I would get $2h = w_1 + w_2 + w_3$ as expected. However, since $f$ is constant, I derive the exact same condition. Setting $f(x) = x$ then gives me $0 = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_2x_2$, and again the extra condition won't help since $\int_{-h}^{h} -x = 0$ aswell. This pattern seems to continue as I use higher order polynomials, so I think that I must be using this symmetric condition wrong. Any help with where to go from here would be very much appreciated.

Comment: (1) as written, your symmetry condition does not make much sense. That equation is always true for any function $f$. And (2) what kind of quadrature rule do you want? You can choose any $x_i$ you want, and any $w_i$ that satisfy $2h=w_1+w_2+w_3$ to get *some* consistent quadrature rule. Though it wouldnt be very good for most choices...

Comment: @Simon this is basically what I thought, it seems like useless information. Usually with these problems we're told that it's exact up to say, cubics, and you can then set `f(x) = 1,x,x^2,x^3` to find up to four constants. The fact there is six unknowns here suggets it should be exact for quintics, however the resulting system of equations will be quite complicated.

Comment: Actually no. The x can be chosen complety arbitrary and by adjusting the w you can always get exact up to quadratic. There are better and worse choices for the x, but there is no way to achieve quintic exactness with three points.

Comment: You're totally right, thank you for the input. I didn't even consider how only three points would limit the accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably what is meant by the symmetry condition is this (though the phrasing is not completely clear):

Exact integrals always have the symmetry $\int f(x) = \int f(-x)$, so it would be nice if your quadrature-rule had this symmetry too. I.e.
$$w_1f(x_1) + w_2f(x_2) + w_3f(x_3) \stackrel{!}{=} w_1f(-x_1) + w_2f(-x_2) + w_3f(-x_3)$$
for all functions $f$ (not only for low-order polynomials). You should convince yourself that the only way to achieve this symmetry is to choose $x_2=0$ and $x_1=-x_3$. This should simplify the rest of your calculations a bit as well.

Comment: I am having some trouble however, if we take $f(x) = x$, then wouldn't the above equation imply that all $x_i = 0$? Since e.g $f(x_1) = f(-x_1)$? I'm not sure how this relation allows you to derive $x_2 = 0$ and $x_1 = -x_3$ specifically.

Comment: In order for the both sides to be equal (for all possible functions $f$), the points $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ have to be the same as $\{-x_1,-x_2,-x_3\}$. This is possible in two different ways: either the $x_i$ is already zero, so the minus sign does not do anything. Or: there are two points which are the negative of one another, i.e. $\{x_1,x_3\}=\{-x_3,-x_1\}$. For this to work you will also need $w_1=w_3$. You have three points in total, and you know that choosing the same $x$ multiple times is not helpful. So it is necessary to choose one of the $x$ as zero, and the other two as a $\pm$ pair.

Comment: This makes a little more sense, but why do only two of points need to be equal to the negative of eachother? I just don't understand why the alternative of all the points being equal to $0$, is only one $x_i = 0$ and the others being a $\pm$ pair. Is there a way to see why this is the case in a more algebraic sense?